# Most performant (better than mine) way to check if any image is duplicated in some folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy

Im not sure if im doing this right.
I have created multiply "copys" of multiply files, all of them should be different in some way (image augmentation).
Now, because maybe the odds are against me i want to check if any of the created files are equal to any other of those created files. Either the odds are with me or i messed up the code badly. Because there are alot of files i can't check them manually. Maybe there would be a faster way than 2 for loops.

I have the following Code.

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import numpy
import time
import datetime


start_time = time.time()
print(datetime.datetime.now().time())

img_dir = sys.argv[1] 
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
something_went_wrong = False

for f1 in files:
    for f2 in files:
        if f1 != f2:
            if open(f1,"rb").read() == open(f2,"rb").read():
                something_went_wrong = True
                print(f1)
                print(f2)
                print("---")

print(something_went_wrong)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: I would probably create a list of all filenames, and compare the list and a set of the list for length. Then take anything in the list that isn't in the set and hash it using `hashlib` and compare the f1 and f2 values. Although it looks like you're doing a nested loop through the same list `files` so you're going to find a ton of "duplicates" which aren't really...

Comment: i mean showing the same picture, i guess. Like if the pixels are the same it should set "something_went_wrong" to True if they pixel are a bit off it should not be set to True.

currently the boolean is never set True. Thats why asking the question, because i assume maybe some of the images showing exactly the same picture (pixel-wise)

Comment: In fact, you could just read all the images and put them into a `set` and check the size of the set. Only problem might be if there are really a lot of images and they are quite large so having them all in memory at the same time is a problem.

Comment: An additional alternative is to not write any code at all, instead using one of the many file duplicate finder tools freely available on the web. If you're learning how to detect duplicates, it's one thing, but if you just want to get a job done don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JonahBishop i guess i found the answer i was looking for. Damn didnt thought about that one :) thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to use a hash as suggested. If one pixel changed, the hash also change.

```
import hashlib
def hash_file(filename):
   # use sha1 or sha256 or other hashing algorithm
   h = hashlib.sha1()

   # open file and read it in chunked
   with open(filename,'rb') as file:
       chunk = 0
       while chunk != b'':
           chunk = file.read(1024)
           h.update(chunk)

   # return string
   return h.hexdigest()
```

https://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-files-with-python/

It is not influenced by filename or metadata! Put the results in a dataframe than it is easy to get the duplicates

Comment: hash is a long operation, Not sure you win again direct comparison.

Comment: you need only one loop to identify your duplicates. With two for loops you have a n^2 runs. If you have 1000 files you need 1million comparissons.

Comment: You are right. What I want to say is that generally there are few duplicates. You just have to compare files of same size. Most of the time at most 2 files have the same size, and the direct comparison is better. Your solution is good if all files in a directory have same size (possible with raw images).

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a hashing function combined with a dictionary of the file list with a count of the number of times each element appears - a slight expansion on the other approach.

Presumably you're talking about duplicate filenames in different folders, which would mean I would put the initial `file_list` together in a slightly different way, but this is the basis for how I would address this issue (depending on what `glob.glob` returns)

```
import hashlib


file_list = []

def test_hash(filename_to_test1, filename_to_test2):
    """
    """
    filename_seq = filename_to_test1, filename_to_test2
    output = []
    for fname in filename_seq:
        with open(fname, "rb") as opened_file:
            file_data = opened_file.readlines()
            file_data_as_string = b"".join(file_data)
            _hash = hashlib.sha256()
            _hash.update(file_data_as_string)
            output.append(_hash.hexdigest())
    if output[0] == output[1]:
        print "File match"
    else:
        print "Mismatch between file and reference value"

possible_duplicates = {}
for idx, fname in enumerate(file_list):
    if fname in possible_duplicates:
        possible_duplicates[fname].append(idx)
    elif fname not in possible_duplicates:
        possible_duplicates[fname] = [idx]

for fname in possible_duplicates:
    if len(possible_duplicates[fname]) > 1:
        for idx, list_item in enumerate(possible_duplicates[fname]):
            test_hash(possible_duplicates[fname][0], possible_duplicates[fname][idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, grouping  by size save time:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict
def fin_dup(dir):
    files=defaultdict(set)
    res=[]
    for fn in os.listdir(dir):
        if os.path.isfile(fn):
            files[os.stat(fn).st_size].add(fn) # groups files by size

    for size,s in sorted(files.items(),key=lambda x : x[0],reverse=True): #big first 
        while s:
            fn0=s.pop()
            s0={fn0}
            for fn in s:
                if open(fn0,'rb').read() == open(fn,'rb').read(): s0.add(fn)
            s -= s0
            if len(s0) > 1: res.append(s0)
    return res
```

This function take less than 1 second to scan a directory with 1000 files and find 79 duplicates. Just hashing files costs 10 seconds.